# Método Trim, ¿Cómo eliminar espacios y caracteres especiales entre cadenas de caracteres?

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo hacer con el método trim que elimine cualquier carácter especial, incluido los espacios en blanco de una cadena de caracteres?.

```
5N0 839 167 B  GRU
5*6 839 461 D
5C/ 854 855    9B9
5C6 8@9 431    5AP
@N0 839 885 H
5@6 845 025 A
```

Intento aplicar este metodo, pero no me resulta:

```
System.out.println(text.trim());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `trim()` lo que hace es eliminar los espacios en blanco al inicio y al final de la palabra, en tu caso podrías usar el método `replaceAll()`, que recibe un patrón a seguir y por lo que lo reemplazara: ejemplo:

```
text.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z]", "")
```

que indica que reemplace todo aquello que no sea numero, letra mayúscula o minúscula por un `""`

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funciono!

Answer (score 3):

El método **[trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())** puede ayudar únicamente a eliminar espacios en los extremos de la cadena.

considero que en este caso es mejor usar el método [**replace()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), reemplazando espacios:

```
text.replace(" ", "");
```

de esta forma eliminas los espacios entre los caracteres y no es necesario el método **[trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())** .

Ejemplo:

```
String text = " 5N0 839 167 B  GRU ";    

text = text.replace(" ", "");
System.out.println(text);
```

tendría como salida:

```
5N0839167BGRU
```

---

#### Eliminar espacios y caracteres especiales.

Lo que requieres en realidad es eliminar además de espacios, caracteres especiales, para esto es recomendable hacer uso de una REGEX:

```
replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "")
```

Ejemplo:

```
    String text = " 5C6 8@9 431    5AP ";
    
    text = text.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "");
    System.out.println(text);
```

tendría como salida:

```
5C6894315AP
```

Answer (score 1):

Trim no hace eso que vos queres.

El metodo [String.Trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) dice en su documentación

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted.

o sea:

> Regresa una copia de la cadena, con espacios en blanco de adelante y
>   atras removidos.

O sea, nada que ver.

Para lo que vos queres hacer, existe [`String.ReplaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) (y algunas variantes)

Por ejemplo, si quisieras eliminar todos los espacios de tu cadena, podrias hacer algo asi:

```
text.ReplaceAll(" ","");
```

Y si text fuera

> 5N0 839 167 B  GRU

Entonces esto devolveria:

> 5N0839167BGRU

Comment: Solo te puse un ejemplo, necesitas una expresion regular completa, sabiendo cuales son todos los caracteres especiales que queres eliminar. @IgmerRodriguez

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por esta ayuda , pues la parte de  "Eliminar espacios y caracteres especiales" me cubrio un problema que tenia bastante sin resolver ya que segun lo que estaba haciendo estaba perfecto , pero no podia hacerlo andar , y resulta que tenia un String con elementos "invisibles" ( en este caso espacios ) que tomaba de un txt y me hizo perder mucho tiempo , pero agregando   replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "")  se me termino automaticamente el problema !!!! millones de gracias !!!!!

Comment: La sección de respuestas es para las propuestas de solución, no para comentarios de agradecimiento. Si una respuesta te fue útil, _dale un voto a favor._ Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio y lee [answer].